# Result of an operator if different data types as arguments? (C)

Tags: c, operators

I haven't been able to find an answer to the following question.

My question is:

What is the result of an operator when different data types (like int, or float) are being operated on?

For example,

```
float * int = ?

float / int = ?
```

We know that operations on same data types give results of the same data type. For instance,

```
float * float = float
```

But I wanted to know what happens in this other case?

This question has probably already been discussed here, but it has been hard for me to find something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When operating on values if differing types, the operands undergo the **usual arithmetic conversions.**.  These are specified in section 6.3.1.8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

> First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is long double
>   , the other operand   is   converted,   without   change   of   type
>   domain,   to   a   type   whose corresponding real type is long double
>   .
>
> Otherwise,  if  the  corresponding  real  type  of  either  operand 
>   is double , the  other operand   is   converted,   without   change
>   of   type   domain,   to   a   type   whose corresponding real type is
>   double .
>
> Otherwise,  if  the  corresponding  real  type  of  either  operand 
>   is float ,  the  other operand   is   converted,   without   change
>   of   type   domain,   to   a   type   whose corresponding real type is
>   float .
>
> Otherwise,  the  integer  promotions  are  performed  on  both 
>   operands.   Then  the following rules are applied to the promoted
>   operands:
>
> - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>     needed.
> - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>     unsigned integer  types,  the  operand  with  the  type  of  lesser 
>     integer  conversion  rank  is converted to the type of the operand
>     with greater rank.
> - Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has 
>     rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other 
>     operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is 
>     converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
>     type.
> - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>     represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>     integer type, then the  operand  with  unsigned  integer  type  is 
>     converted  to  the  type  of  the operand with signed integer type.
> - Otherwise,   both   operands   are   converted   to   the   unsigned
>     integer   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>     integer type.

In the case of a `float` and an `int` as operands to `*` or `/`, the `int` operand will be converted to `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Before performing the arithmetic operation, the compiler arranges for the ["usual arithmetic conversions"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) to be performed.

The precise rules are a slightly complicated, and well documented in the provided link, but the basic idea is:

1. If either argument is a floating point type, both arguments are converted to the more precise floating point between the two arguments.
2. Otherwise, if both arguments are integer types, they are first promoted to at least `int`, and then if the two arguments are not the same width, the narrower one is converted to the type of the other one.

The real rules are more complicated for a couple of reasons:

1. A modern C compiler may implement `complex` (and `imaginary`) types, which play into the conversions.
2. Conversion between signed and unsigned types can be counter-intuitive. If you haven't read the precise rules, it is best to avoid this case.